# Using PosgreSQL array_agg with join alias in JOOQ DSL

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I want to convert this SQL query to JOOQ DSL.

```
select "p".*, array_agg("pmu") as projectmemberusers
from "Projects" as "p"
join "ProjectMemberUsers" as "pmu" on "pmu"."projectId" = "p"."id"
group by "p"."id";
```

Currently i have tried doing something like this using JOOQ:

```
val p = PROJECTS.`as`("p")
val pmu = PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.`as`("pmu")
val query = db.select(p.asterisk(), DSL.arrayAgg(pmu))
        .from(p.join(pmu).on(p.ID.eq(pmu.PROJECTID)))
        .groupBy(p.ID)
```

This does not work because `DSL.arrayAgg` expects something of type `Field<T>` as input.

I am new to JOOQ and not an SQL professional. Detailed explanations and impovement suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I frankly don't see how the original query works. `array_agg()` should receive a column, and you're passing it a table alias. What do I miss?

Comment: Hm, the query actually works for me. Maybe take a look at this https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/12/a-probably-incomplete-comprehensive-guide-to-the-many-different-ways-to-join-tables-in-sql/ (bottom of the page "Alternative syntaxes: PostgreSQL")

Comment: @AlexeySoshin: You an reference a table in the projection to create nested records in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LukasEder, yep, already confirmed it, although it's not documented well in PostgreSQL. Is my assumption correct that it's still not supported by jOOQ, though?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin: That's right, it's currently not supported. It's possible to compare two tables `t1 = t2`, but it's not possible yet to project them. Nested records are still experimental in jOOQ.

Comment: @LukasEder is there any alternative syntax? And are you planning to suupport this in some future release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the syntax indeed works, checked this in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e45b7/3

But it's not documented in detail: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE

That's probably the reason jOOQ doesn't support this currently: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DSL.java#L16856

The only syntax that will work currently is with a single field: `DSL.arrayAgg(pmu.field(1))`

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a way to express PostgreSQL's "anonymous" nested records through the jOOQ API, similar to what is requested in this feature request: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2360

This is currently not possible in the jOOQ API as of version 3.11, but it definitely will be in the future.

#### Workaround 1

You could try using the experimental [`DSL.rowField()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#rowField-org.jooq.Row2-) methods on a `Row[N]<...>` representation of your table type. This may or may not work yet, as the feature is currently not supported.

#### Workaround 2

A workaround is to create a type:

```sql
create type my_type as (...) -- Same row type as your table
```

And a view:

```sql
create view x as
select "p".*, array_agg("pmu"::my_type) as projectmemberusers
from "Projects" as "p"
join "ProjectMemberUsers" as "pmu" on "pmu"."projectId" = "p"."id"
group by "p"."id";
```

And then use the code generator to pick up the resulting type.

Comment: How can i get a `Row[N]<...>` representation of a table type? I tried doing `DSL.arrayAgg(DSL.rowField(pmu.fieldsRow()))`. But `rowField(..)` can´t be called with that parameter.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Generated tables have generated `row()` methods. Does that help? If not, feel free to ask a new question

Comment: I created a follow up question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003995/how-to-get-a-row-representation-of-a-generated-table