# How to get a Row representation of a generated table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I want to get `Row[N]<...>` representation of a generated JOOQ table type. I want to use it in this context:

```
val p = PROJECTS.`as`("p")
val pmu = PROJECTMEMBERUSERS.`as`("pmu")
val query = db
    .select(p.asterisk(), DSL.arrayAgg(DSL.rowField(<-- insert Row[N]<...> here -->)))
    .from(p.join(pmu).on(p.ID.eq(pmu.PROJECTID)))
    .groupBy(p.ID)
```

I already tried inserting `pmu.fieldsRow()`, but `DSL.rowField(...)` expects another parameter type.

> Error:(39, 58) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied [...]

This question is a follow up question to [Using PosgreSQL array_agg with join alias in JOOQ DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753861/using-posgresql-array-agg-with-join-alias-in-jooq-dsl) but should be self contained.

Answer (score 4):

#### Missing feature in jOOQ 3.11

There seems to be a missing feature in the jOOQ code generator, a generated `Table.fieldsRow()` overridden method that provides a more narrow, covariant `Row[N]<...>` return type. I've created a feature request for this, to be implemented in jOOQ 3.12:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7809

Also missing, an overloaded `DSL.rowField(RowN)` method:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7810

#### Workaround, list columns explicitly

This is the most obvious workaround, which you obviously want to avoid: Listing all the column names explicitly:

```
row(pmu.COL1, pmu.COL2, ..., pmu.COLN)
```

#### Workaround, use generated records

There already *is* such a generated method in generated records. As a workaround, you could use

```
new ProjectMembersUsersRecord().fieldsRow();
```

#### Workaround, extend the code generator

You can implement #7809 yourself already now, by extending the `JavaGenerator` with a custom code section:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! When using workaround 2 JOOQ is generating the correct SQL. Executing the generated SQL by hand returns the desired result. Letting JOOQ execute the query does not throw any exception, but does not return any of the nested rows either.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Huh, is that related to the usage of the asterisk? Will try this later

Comment: I tried it without the asterisk: `db.select(PROJECTS.ID, DSL.arrayAgg(DSL.rowField(ProjectmemberusersRecord().fieldsRow())).as("memberusers"))` returns the project id and `{null}` as memberusers.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that when executing the query using `.fetch()` does not return the nested rows. However getting the sql from the query and excecuting the sql using `create.fetch(sql)` is working perfectly fine. Seems to me that this is a bug.

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Yes, most certainly a bug

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: I cannot seem to reproduce getting `{null}` in this case. I could have a closer look at a more complete example to help reproduce the problem, if you're interested in providing such an example on the issue tracker: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new